# MongoDB database errors

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm currently working on a remote ubuntu 16 server. I've installed Apache2, PHP 7 & MongoDB on it. Everything is working perfectly individually but, when i try to connect MongoDB using a PHP program I get an error relating to database and collection creation. All I want is to connect to MongoDB and create a database and collection in it. I searched for the solution but couldn't find any.

```
<?php
    $m = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    echo "connected to database";

    $db = $m->myTestDb;
    echo'<br/>';

    echo "database myTestDb selected";

    $collection = $db->createCollection("user");
    echo'<br/>';

    echo"Collection created successfully";
    echo'<br/>';

    $document = array(
        "id"=>"012123123123121",
        "firstname"=>"john",
        "middlename"=>'steve',
        "lastname"=>"bell",
        "dateofbirth"=>"23/08/1990",
        "age"=>"27",
        "gender"=>"male",
        "aadharno"=>"789456123",
        "passportno"=>"987654321",
        "panno"=>"7539514862",
        "address"=>"london",
        "email"=>"john@gmail.com",
        "contactno"=>"7777777777",
        "username"=>"john",
        "password"=>"john",
        "joiningdate"=>"15/12/2017",
        "empid"=>"01",
        "department"=>"computer",
        "designation"=>"developer"

        );

     if($collection->insert($document))
    {
        echo "Collection Created !";
    }
    //echo"Document inserted successfully";
    echo'<br/>';

?>
```

These are the errors that I'm getting

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined property: MongoDB\\Driver\\Manager::$myTestDb in 
/var/www/mongo/testmongo.php on line 5

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function 
createCollection() on null in /var/www/mongo/testmongo.php:10\nStack 
trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/mongo/testmongo.php on line 10
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you installed mongodb driver in php : http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php?

Comment: @MihirBhende I followed the step from this tutorial https://tecadmin.net/setup-mongodb-php5-apache2-ubuntu/#

Comment: if you do phpinfo(), are you able to see mongo driver in there?

Comment: @MihirBhende yes I do see MongoDB support enabled

Comment: Can you try new \MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017"); added extra \ at the start

Comment: @MihirBhende This isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get `myTestDb` property of `MongoDB\Driver\Manager` while there is no such property nor magic `__get` method that would handle the situation - this warrants the notice. I believe you wanted your code to look more like (note that I'm instantiating different class)

```
$client = new \MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$db = $client->myTestDb;
```

You can refer to ["Using the PHP Library"](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.tutorial.library.php) for more details on how to interact with the driver and library.

Comment: I tried this but this is'nt working. myTestDb is my database name that I want to create

Comment: It gives me an error that the class MongoDB\\Client was not found.

Comment: yes I did and changed my code but I can't put in the autoload.php file so the code isn't working as it should. Also, I'm not using composer. I'm using MobaXterm for my remote server

Comment: I'm not sure how these two are connected, but you either need the library up and running or write what it's doing on your own, you can check its source code here: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library